# Sprites overlapping when moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

When enemies move toward the player, they begin to overlap. I've tried to find a solution for this but most things I've found are things I"m already doing. The Enemies all have box collides and things collide normally with them when they're still. When they move, however, they clip through all other colliders. They move using velocity rather than translate. Player movement uses the same format but while moving I still collide with walls or other colliders. What is causing them to ignore collisions?

```
Vector2 moveDestination = this.transform.position - player.transform.position;
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = (speed * -moveDestination.normalized * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely confident with this, but colliders clipping through other colliders are usually caused by velocity being too high. Think of it as object A speeding through object B because it's too fast, and it's usually more of a rigidbody issue than a collider one.

Try setting the moving rigidbody's Collision Detection mode to "Continuous Dynamic", and the other colliders to "Continuous"

Hope this helps :)